# Swift: Dynamically Constraint Button Size According to Screen Size

Tags: swift

I am attempting to dynamically constraint my buttons in a stackView according to the size of my screen. The end goal is to constraint the button's radius to be 50% of each stack in my stackView.

I have three buttons in the stackView. My code so far:

```
class PeopleContainerView: UIView {

    let stackContainerView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        return v
    }()

    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let sv = UIStackView()
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.distribution = .fillEqually
        sv.backgroundColor = .gray
        return sv
    }()

    let previousButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        b.backgroundColor = .faintGray
        b.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_keyboard_arrow_left"), for: .normal)
        return b
    }()

    let nextButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        b.backgroundColor = .faintGray
        b.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_keyboard_arrow_right"), for: .normal)
        return b
    }()

    let chatButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        b.backgroundColor = .customPink
        b.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_forum"), for: .normal)
        return b
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(stackContainerView)
        stackContainerView.addSubview(stackView)

        stackContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stackContainerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        stackContainerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
        stackContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true

        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackContainerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackContainerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75).isActive = true
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackContainerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(previousButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(chatButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(nextButton)

        //Below two lines break the constraints
        previousButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3 * 0.5).isActive = true
        previousButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3 * 0.5).isActive = true

    }

}
```

Thereafter at viewController, I'll do a addSubview() of this view. The last two lines of my current code does resize my buttons at this moment, but breaks other constraints. Eventually, I would need to add a cornerRadius dynamically to it as well. Pls see screenshots:

With last two lines -

[image]

Without the last two lines -

[image]

It would be great if anyone could advice where have I gone wrong here pls, thanks.

EDIT1: 
My end goal is to achieve the following UI:
[image]

EDIT2:
My attempt on Rikesh's suggestion

```
class PeopleContainerView: UIView {

    let stackContainerView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let sv = UIStackView()
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.distribution = .fillEqually
        return sv
    }()

    let previousButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        b.backgroundColor = .faintGray
        b.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_keyboard_arrow_left"), for: .normal)
        return b
    }()

    let nextButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        b.backgroundColor = .faintGray
        b.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_keyboard_arrow_right"), for: .normal)
        return b
    }()

    //New attempt to create a custom Wrapper View
    let chatButton: ButtonView = {
        let b = ButtonView()
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return b
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(stackContainerView)
        stackContainerView.addSubview(stackView)

        stackContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stackContainerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        stackContainerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
        stackContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true

        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75).isActive = true
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(previousButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(chatButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(nextButton)
    }
}

class ButtonView: UIView {
    let containerView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .customPink
        return v
    }()

    let button: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        b.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        return b
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(button)

        containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

Results when the peopleContainerView is toggled on:

[image]

Results when it is not toggled on:

[image]

Comment: What is the goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @SQLiteNoob apologies that I wasn't clear enough. Have edited the post to include a pictorial description of my end goal.

Comment: How about adding a view as a wrapper view for each buttons and add your constraints to it?

Comment: @RikeshSubedi I have tried this method, but the constraints doesn't work. The buttons will appear in mid air and not get constraint to the containerView.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If I have understood your problem correctly, I would like to suggest the solution as follows:

1. First add 1 view into a stackview
2. Make stackview it equals spacing
3. Add button into the view
4. add constraints to buttons

   a. Aspect ratio 1:1

   b. height = 0.6 * height of parent view

   c. center horizontally

   d. center vertically
5. Make 3 copies of the view inside stackview

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, but it creates more bugs. I do it programmatically by creating a containerView, and adding the button to the containerView. The containerView does not get anchored to the parentContainerView when this parentContainerView is being toggled.

Comment: @Koh it was easy for me to explain in the storyboard. I know you need to write so many lines of code for the same.

Comment: Rikesh, you may see my attempt on ur suggestion in the edit

Comment: @Koh, i think you code is just fine after little bit change.